# Alternative to triggerEvent attribute in mak:addForm

Tags: makumba

According to the [documentation](http://www.makumba.org/page/Web20HowTo#section-Web20HowTo-Introduction), the triggerEvent attribute can be used in mak:form, mak:newForm or mak:editForm. I would like however to use the same feature in mak:addForm, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there an alternative way to get the partial reload feature in mak:addForm without this attribute?